# What is lettuce library for?

Tags: python-2.7, lettuce

I have found code within an open source project which uses lettuce library extensively.

It seems  that lettuce is a tool to support "Behaviour Driven Development".

I'm wondering whether code based on lettuce is only for testing purposes, or is it actually used as a "production code"?

I would appreciate if someone could explain in plain English what is the purpose of lettuce library and how is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lettuce library is used to test code before it is released to production systems.

Lettuce is meant to describe Behavior Driven Development.

The idea behind lettuce is that before coding up any functionality, you first describe your what you want your functions to do with written descriptions. Then following your descriptions, you write out the core steps of what you expect from the function. After doing so, you implement the functionality you originally described and test the results.

You can repeat the cycle above, each time adding additional descriptions. After each iteration, you develop more confidence in the correctness of your code.

Reference:

http://lettuce.it/tutorial/simple.html